# How to generate dbg files with CLion for use with VerySleepy

Tags: c++, debugging, cmake, clion, verysleepy

I have some memory leaks in my application, and I'd like to debug them. The tool for Windows that I want to use is [Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy/). The problem is that when I use the software, it cannot figure out what corresponding source file of the problem is.

[image]

From what I figured out I need a symbol file. With the compiler I use (MinGW-w64) I have .dbg files. But even though I have specified that clion should compile with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` I cannot find any .dbg file in my working directory.

What could be the cause? Keep in mind that I use CLION.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to config cmake for strip file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675403/how-to-config-cmake-for-strip-file) or [How to generate gcc debug symbol outside the build target?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866721/how-to-generate-gcc-debug-symbol-outside-the-build-target)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the latest development version of Very Sleepy? It has improved support for reading MinGW debug information:

https://github.com/VerySleepy/verysleepy#download