# CMake: Platform independent binary stripping for release builds

Tags: c++, cmake, strip

How can you add binary stripping to `CMake` for `gcc` and `clang` as a post-processing step but only in release builds? `MSVC` strips by default so it does not have to be handled.

One of the problems is that `clang` does not have a `-s` compilation flag but `gcc` does [so doing it this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676023/3764804) does not work.

Another idea is to use the strip command. The `-s` switch again exists on `Linux` but not on `XCode` (this is `Apple`'s development toolchain).

So the final choice is to use the `strip` command without any arguments besides the binary itself which appears to be a decent generic solution. How can this be used in `CMake`?

Comment: Here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/53409479/8034839) is how I do for Android CMake to invoke `strip` command.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `CMake` `add_custom_command` can execute post build commands such as `strip`. The `PROJECT_NAME` variable is defined as your target binary e.g.

```
# Set the project name
set(PROJECT_NAME "MyProject")
project(${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Place the following code after `add_executable` of your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Strip binary for release builds
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND $<$<CONFIG:release>:${CMAKE_STRIP} ${PROJECT_NAME}>)
```

`CMAKE_STRIP` is the file path to the platform's `strip` utility (e.g. `/usr/bin/strip` on `Linux`). The `$<$<CONFIG:cfg>:str>` generator expression will expand to `str` when building the configuration `cfg`, and to an empty string otherwise. In this scenario, this directly means "call strip when building in Release, and do nothing otherwise". Note that the `CONFIG` generator is case insensitive on your build type, and will work when using multi-config generators.

Comment: In my case, the command must split into multiple section, like: COMMAND "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:${CMAKE_STRIP}>" --strip-unneeded "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:$<TARGET_FILE:${COMMON_LIB}>>" ,   as $<$<CONFIG:release>:${CMAKE_STRIP} ${PROJECT_NAME}> will be parse as executable command.

Comment: Link to the docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events

Comment: Hello @BullyWiiPlaza, I have a similar issue and I am trying your solution. But I am getting error like: `add_custom_command Wrong syntax.  A TARGET and OUTPUT can not both be specified.` Can you please let me know what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 3):

While using [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events), I was having issues with the `COMMAND` generator expression containing spaces. The `ARGS` option can be used while still toggling the inclusion of the custom command through a generator expression for the `COMMAND` option:

```
add_custom_command(
  TARGET "${TARGET}" POST_BUILD
  DEPENDS "${TARGET}"
  COMMAND $<$<CONFIG:release>:${CMAKE_STRIP}>
  ARGS --strip-all $<TARGET_FILE:${TARGET}>
)
```

This results in `strip --strip-all myapp` being called when config is release, but no command being called when it's not, despite the args being specified in a separate option.

Comment: Hello @inkychris, I have a similar issue and I am trying your solution. But I am getting error like: `add_custom_command Wrong syntax.  A TARGET and OUTPUT can not both be specified.` Can you please let me know what could be the issue here?

Comment: I can't really help without seeing what your actual command call looks like, but the error message suggests that you're trying to specify the `TARGET` and `OUTPUT`, which `add_custom_command` doesn't support. If you're using this on a target, you don't need to specify `OUTPUT`.

Comment: At first this doesn't work, but changing
`ARGS --strip-all $<TARGET_FILE:${TARGET}>
`
into 
`ARGS --strip-all "${TARGET}"`
will work

Answer (score 0):

At least in modern versions of CMake, you can choose to strip the binaries at install time: either by building the `install/strip` target instead of the `install` target, or by passing `--strip` to `cmake --install` (see [documentation for `cmake --install`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#install-a-project))