# How to properly build configuration without debug info in Cmake? | Cmake is ignoring CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross-compile a "Release" version of C++ based application using `cmake` and `make`. Its for `Makefile` based generators. But, somehow passing the command `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE` is ignored by the `cmake`. I have also added below commands to `CMakeLists.txt` file.

```
add_compile_options(
        $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-g3>
        $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-Og>
        $<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-O3>
        )

add_compile_definitions(
        $<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:RELEASE>
        )

add_link_options($<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:RELEASE>)
```

In the `CMakeCache.txt` file I could see `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RELEASE` is set. I am calling below commands to cross-compile:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE ..
make
```

Configuration is successful and `make` is also successful. But generated file is with debug info. I want to generate without debug info(Release config)

```
ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, BuildID[sha1]=cc8fff.., for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

My goal is to `strip` this debug info.

I also tried with `add_custom_commands` to strip binary as part of `POST_BUILD` using `CMAKE_STRIP`. In the `CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_custom_command(
TARGET "${TARGET_NAME}" POST_BUILD
DEPENDS "${TARGET_NAME}"
COMMAND $<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:${CMAKE_STRIP}>
ARGS --strip-all $<TARGET_FILE:${TARGET}>
)
```

This is added after `add_executable` section. But while configuration I am getting below error from `cmake`

```
add_custom_command Wrong syntax.  A TARGET and OUTPUT can not both be specified.
```

Can anyone please let me know what is the correct way to generate **Release** version of binary using cmake?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I am working on Ubuntu machine. Please let me know if any info is missing here.

Comment: For debug purposes you could always run `make`  with additional `V=1` option and check which exact parameters are passed to the compiler or linker.

Comment: POST_BUILD is already dependent on TARGET, remove DEPENDS.

Comment: I would vote for duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692348/cmake-platform-independent-binary-stripping-for-release-builds

Comment: For striping debug info use -s link option.

Comment: Why are you using upper case in `RELEASE`/`DEBUG`? The convention  is `Release`/`Debug`. That has nothing to do with your problem, just an observation.

Comment: Hello @273K, I also tried with `add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND $<$<CONFIG:release>:${CMAKE_STRIP} ${PROJECT_NAME}>)` But I get same error.
Can you please let me know how to use `-s` link to strip debug info? This would be helpful

Comment: @ixSci, thanks for the info. But I already tried with `Release/Debug`. Its same result

Comment: Why are you striping project name? It should be target file.

Comment: Please show a [mre], setting the build type to release should produce an executable without debug info without having to specify any compile options. Is the debug info perhaps coming from one of the libraries you are linking to?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I could not find any parameters specific to CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE using `make V=1` or `make VERBOSE=1`

Comment: @273K, sorry that solution was copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692348/cmake-platform-independent-binary-stripping-for-release-builds

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675403/how-to-config-cmake-for-strip-file for -s

Comment: " I could not find any parameters specific to CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE using `make V=1` or `make VERBOSE=1`" - Well, it smells like your `add_compile_options` doesn't affect on the target which you want, doesn't it? So the **actual** problem is not about CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE, but about *something else*. Once again, we need to see [mcve], not just a several lines of code.

Comment: Hi @273K, after including -s, binary is stripped. I included `set_target_properties(TARGET_NAME PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS_RELEASE -s)` in `CMakeLists.txt`. I wanted to know whether if this a safer option. And also now it is showing `ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV)`, earlier it was `ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux)`. I hope this is fine.

Comment: did you want `MinSizeRel` ?
ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html